# Enforce Class Only Exists as part of 1 other class

Tags: c#

I have a class that I want to be a property of another class.  However, I only want this one other class to be able to have a property of that 2nd class.

I thought I would create a nested private class.  However, doing that, gives me compiler error: "Inconsistent accessibility"

```
class OuterClass
{
    public InnerClass MyInnerClass { get; set; }


    private class InnerClass
    {
        public bool CanItBe { get; set; }
    }
}

class DifferentClass
{
    public InnerClass IWantThisToNotBePossible { get; set; }
}
```

Update: Problem trying to solve

```
Class Bicycle
{
    public WheelSettings MyWheelSettings {get;set;}
}

Class WheelSettings
{
    public decimal SpokeLength {get;set;}
}

Class SteeringWheel 
{
    public WheelSettings MyWheelSettings {get;set;} ==> i want this to be 
    an error -> WheelSettings class cannot be used in any class other than 
    Bicycle
}
```

Comment: You have to make the `InnerClass` type public so that other classes that instantiate `OuterClass` can `get` and `set` the `MyInnerClass` property.

Comment: I don't think this is possible (to create a type that other classes can instantiate but not expose as a property), but it might be helpful if you describe what problem you are trying to solve here. There may be some other way.

Comment: You can't do that. If you want to make it clear what the class is for, name it better: `BicycleWheelSettings`.

Comment: @Blorgbeard -> that's the solution i've come up with too.

Comment: Cool. Just as more justification for why you can't: properties are just syntactical sugar around getter and setter methods. You wouldn't really want to make a rule that "no methods outside this class may accept or return parameters of this type" - what if I want to implement some complex logic in my `BicycleSpeedCalculator`? I have to pass the entire `Bicycle` around instead of looking at just the `WheelSettings`?

Comment: @Blorgbeard - interesting point.  Whether it's a property or a field referenced by getters/setters isn't important.  But i think the bicyclespeedcalculator could/should be a method inside Bicycle or WheelSettings.

Comment: Well, there's got to be something outside the class that wants to use it, or there's no point exposing it, right?

Comment: @Blorgbeard - if you're asking if something will want to use WheelSettings... then yes... they should be able to access it like... MyBicycle.MyWheelSettings.SpokeLength = 5;

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done. If your class exposes a property or method returning `WheelSettings`, the class needs to be public, so that any other class can see that it exists and know what's inside of it.
By rules of C#, this means any code that can see this class exists can hold a reference to it. It can be a local variable, a field, or returned by a method.

If you really want to prevent anyone from misunderstanding the purpose of your class, you can make a public interface.

```cs
public class Bicycle {
   public IWheelSettings MyWheelSettings { get; set; } = new WheelSettings();

   public interface IWheelSettings {
      decimal SpokeLength { get; set; }
   }

   private class WheelSettings : IWheelSettings {
      public decimal SpokeLength { get; set; }
   }
}
```

This way you can prevent anyone *instantiating* instances of `IWheelSettings`, since no class that implements it is publicly known.
Of course, nothing is preventing me from implementing it myself.

BTW, any other class would need to qualify `WheelSettings` with `Bycicle` anyway, so it's pretty obvious that it shouldn't be used in other context already.

```cs
public class Car {
    public Bicycle.WheelSettings settings;
}
```

EDIT: Also, consider this: If instances of `WheelSettings` should never be referenced without the `Bicycle`, why does it exist? Why aren't wheel settings properties of the `Bicycle` itself?